# Which vaccines are important take when traveling to the United States?

Tags: usa, health, vaccinations

Which vaccines are important take when traveling to the United States?

Does each state have different vaccines?

Answer (score 7):

There are no vaccination requirements for visitors entering the US; Loren has posted general vaccination schedules recommended by the CDC for people living in the US (and possibly, as a guideline for others).

However, for traveling to the US, there are no vaccination requirements, as stated plainly at the [CDC website](http://wwwnc.cdc.gov/travel/destinations/traveler/none/united-states):

> CDC Travelers’ Health provides information and health recommendations
>   for US residents traveling internationally. If you live outside the
>   United States and plan to travel here, please check resources in your
>   own country for travel health information.
>
> **There are no vaccination requirements for visitors to the United
>   States.**

The Centers for Disease Control and Prevention (CDC) is the federal agency that oversees things like vaccinations and disease outbreaks throughout the US. They also provide guidelines for vaccination and preventive measures for dealing with diseases.

Comment: There's a big difference between vaccination *requirements* and vaccination *recommendations*. Very few countries have any vaccination requirements. Yellow Fever zone countries checking passengers' yellow fever certificates on arrival is one example of a vaccination *requirement*, where you can be denied entry without proof of vaccination. But even in many cases where you'd be mad to travel without a vaccine, it's rarely a *requirement*.

Answer (score 6):

The Public Health Agency [lists](http://www.phac-aspc.gc.ca/tmp-pmv/countries-pays/country-pays-eng.php?id=459) the following vaccinations to consider for travelling to the US:

- Hepatitis B
- Influenza
- Measles

The [NHS (UK)](http://www.fitfortravel.nhs.uk/destinations/north-america/united-states-of-america.aspx) recommends to get **Tetanus** shot on top of the normal vaccinations.

All those are just meant as suggestions and will depend on a lot of factors such as which vaccinations you already have, when you are travelling (you're unlikely to need a flu shot in summer) and how long you are travelling. The best would probably be to ask your GP.

Comment: (+1) The NHS page is a bit confusing, it lists Tetanus under "other vaccines" but the text below suggests it's part of the regular immunization schedule in the UK, as I would expect.

Comment: @Relaxed Tetanus is part of the regular vaccination schedule - for children only (last scheduled vaccine ~15-16) I'm not actually aware of any population-wide vaccinations for adults in the UK. The effectivness is somewhat reduced with >10 years after the previous administration, so it is often recommended for travellers, those with open wounds, or those in certain occupations.

Comment: Should the Covid vaccine be added?

Comment: @CGCampbell I rolled back your change about the Zika Virus because there is no approved, available vaccine for it. The Canadian travel advice site is confusingly laid out and does appear to list Zika precautions among its vaccine recommendations, but if you click through, the recommended precautions do not (and, presently, can not) include vaccination.

Comment: @mic ok by me. Personally, I don't think this 'answers the question'. It's not a list required by the US, and as the OP is from Brasil, doesn't list what Brasil recommends either.

Answer (score -2):

Here are the CDC recommendations:

http://www.cdc.gov/vaccines/parents/downloads/parent-ver-sch-0-6yrs.pdf

http://www.cdc.gov/vaccines/who/teens/downloads/parent-version-schedule-7-18yrs.pdf

http://www.cdc.gov/vaccines/schedules/downloads/adult/adult-schedule-easy-read.pdf

Note that some insurers cover the HPV vaccine past age 26.

Comment: Since links are unstable, it's best to provide a summary of the content.

Comment: -1 this is for people living in the US, not people traveling to the US.

Comment: @BurhanKhalid But that gives you a good idea of what is considered proper vaccination in the US.